# force kms sync with powershell hangs

Tags: powershell, cmd, tfs-2015, vnext

I have a command in my script.ps1 which is run by a next build step in tfs 2015. I then navigate to the location of office, run the command to force a KMS push like this:

```
cmd.exe dir "C:\apps\MSOffice\Office15\"
cmd.exe "cscript ospp.vbs /act"
```

It gets executed but then it just hangs and nothing happens.  If I execute the command by hand it works without problems.
This only occurs if I do it through powershell - running the command by hand works as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks Micky!, /C helped me debugging.

solution is like this:

```
cmd.exe /c "cd C:\apps\MSOffice\Office15\"
cmd.exe /c "cscript.exe C:\apps\MSOffice\Office15\ospp.vbs /act"
```

need to execute the script VB handler separately from the VB script.
BTW: the reason why im doing this is because i have a build task that will execute this upon 20 build machines simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would call CMD from PowerShell to execute commands that PowerShell can execute directly.

Anyway

Use /C to return when the command is performed

```
cmd.exe /C dir "C:\apps\MSOffice\Office15\"
cmd.exe /C "cscript ospp.vbs /act"
```